# Multimodule Sphinx Leads To Duplicate Static Folder

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-sphinx

My sphinx project has multiple modules. I wanted all the modules to have their separate build.

```
Main
   conf.py
   Module1
       conf.py
   Module2
       conf.py
```

I ran sphinx-build for each of these. In the top level conf.py i made sure to let sphinx know to ignore the module1 and module2 folders.

The build html is organized the same way as the source.

The issue i am having now is that the *same* static folder is repeated three times.

```
Main
   _static
   Module1
       _static
   Module2
       _static
```

I want to only keep the top level static folder, and have the links in Module1 and Module2 refer to that _static folder. Is there a way to do this within sphinx? It seems like the isn't an option to prevent sphinx from copying the _static folder.

Comment: *"I wanted all the modules to have their separate build"*. Why?

Comment: To have a separate, index, search index and module index for each module.

Comment: Having more than one conf.py file in a Sphinx project seems odd. I don't see how that can work.

Comment: I couldn't find an alternative to separate the modules. Otherwise everything is lumped together

Comment: What is it that is "lumped together"? This looks like a possible ["XY problem"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is your actual problem (the one for which you think multiple conf.py files is the solution)?

Comment: All i want is to have an index, search index and module index for each module. When I build each module separately, this is achieved. However if I build everything together all the modules are lumped. For example when I'm the module1 folder and click on "modules" i see all the classes , instead of just the classes of module1. Likewise when in the module1 folder and search for a class, classes in module2 and module3 will also show up